# DAMAGE: after Normal block in deleting SAXParser xerces

Tags: debugging, mfc, xerces

I am working on an old MFC application which uses xerces 2.7 for XML parsing.

In debug mode, while trying to debug a stack corruption, I have been able to narrow down the issue to the following code:

```
BOOL CXMLHandler::LoadFile(CString fileName)
{
XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();

SAXParser* parser = new SAXParser();
delete parser;

XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();

return TRUE;
}
```

while deleting the parser, I get the error

> "DAMAGE: after Normal block (#1695) at 0x0795EEA8."

the SAXParser class is from xerces.

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the code. Can anyone help in finding out what is wrong here. Could a memory leak/corruption elsewhere in the code be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

If that #1695 is the same each time you run add the following to the start of the program:

```
_CrtSetBreakAlloc(1695);
```

Allocation number 1695 is the data that has been damaged. The debugger will halt there.